# Reverse function behavior in Haskell

Tags: haskell, where-clause, reverse, ghci

```hs
digits :: Int -> [Int]
digits n  = reverse (x)
    where x  
            | n < 10 = [n]
            | otherwise = (mod n 10) : (digits (div n 10))
```

```hs
*ghci> digits 1234 = [3,1,2,4]*
```

```hs
digits' :: Int -> [Int]
digits' n  =  (x)
    where x  
            | n < 10 = [n]
            | otherwise = (mod n 10) : (digits' (div n 10))
```

```hs
*ghci>digits' 1234 = [4,3,2,1]*
```

As per my understanding the evaluation of `digits 1234` should be `[1,2,3,4]`. But it seems that I am missing something. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that `digits` reverses the string in each recursive call, not just once at the outer level. Try `digits x = reverse (digits' x)` (or, equivalently, `digits = reverse . digits'`), and see if you can explain the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Notwithstanding the excellent answer by amalloy, here is a way of getting the digits in the expected order without involving the `reverse` library function.

We use the common trick of accumulating the result in some extra argument of the recursive call, (the “*accumulator*”) noted here as `dgs`.

We also use the [`divMod`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:divMod)  library function, which returns a pair containing both the quotient and the remainder.

```
digits :: Int -> [Int]
digits n = go [] n
  where
    base      =  10
    go dgs k  =  if (k < base)  then  (k:dgs)
                                else  let  (q,r) = divMod k base
                                      in   go (r:dgs) q
```

The accumulator grows by successive *prepending* operations, in such a way that the digits end up in the appropriate order.

Comment: Your base case is a little more complicated than necessary. I would write: `digits = go [] where {go dgs 0 = dgs; go dgs k = let (q, r) = divMod k 10 in go (r:dgs) q}`.